# How can you filter for only the max value from from a queried table in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I'm fairly new to Postgresql and my problem can be simplified to the following:
Suppose that I have 2 tables:

Table A:

```
id | join_value | filter_data1 | filter_data2
---------------------------------------------
1  |    1       |      "Yes"   |     1   
2  |    1       |      "Yes"   |     3
3  |    2       |      "No"    |     0
```

Table B:

```
id | join_value | filter_data1 | filter_data2 |   date
---------------------------------------------------------
1  |    3       |      "Yes"   |     0        |  1/3/2021
2  |    1       |      "Yes"   |     17       |  1/3/2021
3  |    1       |      "No"    |     -1       |  1/2/2021
4  |    1       |      "Yes"   |     32       |  1/2/2021
5  |    1       |      "Yes"   |     40       |  1/3/2021
```

I would like to filter these tables on the filter data and then join them on the join value. The catch is that I would then like to only grab the values that have a date == MAX(date). Here is an example of a query that I have attempted.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM A
WHERE filter_data1 = "Yes"
AND filter_data2 > 2) 
AS a_tab
JOIN
(SELECT * FROM B
WHERE filter_data1 = "Yes"
AND filter_data2 > 16)
AS b_tab
ON a_tab.join_value = b_tab.join_value;
```

This would give me the following table:

```
id | join_value | filter_data1 | filter_data2 | id | filter_data1 | filter_data2 |   date
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2  |   1        |    "Yes"     |     3        | 2  |    "Yes"     |     17       | 1/3/2021
2  |   1        |    "Yes"     |     3        | 4  |    "Yes"     |     32       | 1/2/2021
2  |   1        |    "Yes"     |     3        | 5  |    "Yes"     |     40       | 1/3/2021
```

But the problem is, I would like to also do a 'WHERE date = MAX(date)'

The resulting table would be this:

```
id | join_value | filter_data1 | filter_data2 | id | filter_data1 | filter_data2 |   date
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2  |   1        |    "Yes"     |     3        | 2  |    "Yes"     |     17       | 1/3/2021
2  |   1        |    "Yes"     |     3        | 5  |    "Yes"     |     40       | 1/3/2021
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, let me give you a hint, how you can write your existing select query in a way that it is better readable:

```sql
SELECT
    a.*, b.*
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON b.join_value = a.join_value
WHERE a.filter_data1 = 'YES' AND a.filter_data2 > 2 
    AND b.filter_data1 = 'YES' AND b.filter_data2 > 16
```

Now I am going to add another column to this query, that holds the maximum value of the `date` column of the output. Therefore, we can use a `WINDOW FUNCTION`:

```sql
SELECT
    a.*, b.*, MAX(b.date) OVER ()
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON b.join_value = a.join_value
WHERE a.filter_data1 = 'YES' AND a.filter_data2 > 2 
    AND b.filter_data1 = 'YES' AND b.filter_data2 > 16
```

As the `WINDOW FUNCTION` is the part of the query, that is computed in the last step, we cannot add a condition here. So we use this query as a subquery and add the condition to the top-level-query:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        a.*, b.*, MAX(b.date) OVER () AS max_date
    FROM a
    INNER JOIN b ON b.join_value = a.join_value
    WHERE a.filter_data1 = 'YES' AND a.filter_data2 > 2 
        AND b.filter_data1 = 'YES' AND b.filter_data2 > 16
) t
WHERE t.date = t.max_date
```

This should give you the required results.